# Is it possible to pull images from ECR without using docker login

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-ecr

I have an ECR and EC2 instance running docker. What I want to do is to pull images without doing `docker login` first.

Is it possible at all? If yes what kind of policy should I attach to EC2 instance and/or ECR repo? I did a lot of experiments, but did not succeed.

And please - no suggestions on how to use aws get-login. My aim is to get rid of it by using IAM policy/roles.

Comment: something like https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/authenticating-amazon-ecr-repositories-for-docker-cli-with-credential-helper/ ?

Comment: Almost. But it still need the .aws/credentials. What I want to do is to pull images without any credentials, just using IAM profile attached to the instance.

Comment: That page specifically says "IAM role for Amazon EC2" is one of the options for credentials delivery.  Which it basically always will be for anything aws builds, thank goodness.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that, but further no information/examples. This is exactly my problem - there is almost no information on this topic available, and everything what I can guess (for instance similar to S3) does not work for ECR - docker still complains about missing basic auth.

Answer (score 1):

To use an EC2 Role without having to use `docker login`, https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper can be used.

Place the `docker-credential-ecr-login` binary on your PATH and set the contents of your `~/.docker/config.json` file to be:

```
{
    "credsStore": "ecr-login"
}
```

Now commands such as `docker pull` or `docker push` will work transparently.

> My aim is to get rid of it by using IAM policy/roles.

I don't see how this is possible since some form of authentication is required.